# Dynamically GroupBy Property List of Name and Values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I cannot seem to figure this one out. I found this on SO already, [LINQ: grouping based on property in sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258093/linq-grouping-based-on-property-in-sublist). However, I must group Documents by multiple Name-Value pairs provided at runtime. Here are my types:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I have:

```
var groupableProperties = new List<string> { "Color", "Shape" };

var documents = new List<Document>()
{
    new Document()
    {
         Name = "sample.txt",
         Metadata = new List<Metadata>()
         {
             new Metadata() { Name = "Color", Value = "Red" },
             new Metadata() { Name = "Shape", Value = "Circle" },
             new Metadata() { Name = "Texture", Value = "Rough" }
         }
    },
    new Document()
    {
        Name = "sample2.txt",
        Metadata = new List<Metadata>()
        {
            new Metadata() { Name = "Color", Value = "Red" },
            new Metadata() { Name = "Shape", Value = "Circle" },
            new Metadata() { Name = "Texture", Value = "Smooth" }
        }
    },
    new Document()
    {
        Name = "sample3.txt",
        Metadata = new List<Metadata>()
        {
            new Metadata() { Name = "Color", Value = "Red" }
        }
    }
};
```

With groupableProperties provided at runtime, I would like to end up with 2 groups of **Documents**, Group 1: sample.txt, sample2.txt and Group 2: sample3.txt.

Comment: Here's a guy exploring options for dynamic OrderBy, a very similar problem. His solutions might help you: http://byatool.com/general-coding/orderby-using-a-property-name/

Comment: Can you provide more information? This is a little vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is

```
from d in documents
group d by string.Join("", d.Metadata
                            .Where(m => groupableProperties.Contains(m.Name))
                            .OrderBy (x => x.Name)
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                      ) into g
select g;
```

This creates two groups, having keys `RedCircle` (sample.txt, sample2.txt) and `Red` (sample3.txt).

The ordering by name ensures that the key strings will always be the same when the names in `groupableProperties` are found.